# I'm picking up on Brent Hackers' new idea

Tags: riddle, visual

A single word connects these images:

[image: That thing you sleep on]   [image: Evidence of combustion.]
[image: Place where you can pile your trash]   [image: Those things on your keyboard or mouse right now]
[image: Eating utensil]   [image: Road sign]
[image: Part of a boat]   [image: Part of a recreational vehicle]

The final two aren't as intuitive but the same word can be found within them:
(You can click on either for a larger version.)
[image: Ancient structures]  [image: Real celestial bodies]

**What is the word, and what are the connections?**

Comment: I'm not a psychic but this is going to become a phase isn't it

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Remember JLee's Words™ and Phrases™?

Comment: *Shudders* Sadly yes... :P

Comment: Gosh more... Are each of these going to blow up on HNQ too?

Comment: Is the title a clue here too?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Yes

Comment: Also, is me or Mith correct?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil You both had what I thought were valid answers although I've never before heard of a fork in time and seven times table was a pretty weak connection. I added two more images in an effort to improve my question / narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: @Engineer Toast I edited my answer to include the last 2. Very clever! If there is anything else I missed let me know or you can accept it as the answer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is:

> Truck

The title refers to:

> Pickup Truck

Also:

> Truck Bed
> Fire Truck
> Dump Truck
> Hand Truck (Also know as a hand cart)
> Fork Truck (Fork lift)
> Truck Stop
> Skateboard Trucks

Finally(very clever by the way):

> Moonstruck
>  Wonderstruck

Comment: `Truck` is what I was thinking of, yes. The last two are a little different, remember. There is more than one moon in that picture.

Comment: Change moon to moons in your answer and connect the two words, you'll get the word which means "Showing irrational behaviour".

Comment: Same goes for the previous one, which i think is Wonders.

Comment: Thank you @Piotr! I wasn't thinking outside the box enough for those when I wrote the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Think I got it:

> Time

Explanations:

Title:

> Pick up time

Images:

> Bedtime
> TBO: Burning time
> Waste of time
> Time on your hands
> Fork in Time
> Stop time
> Seven times table?
> Spacetime

Note: This was wrong and the images not included here were edited in after to make the answer more unique

Comment: Maybe: Burning Time for the Fire, Time on Hands for the hand, Spacetime for the celestial objects?

Comment: @TwoBitOperation ah thanks, hadn't heard of a couple of those

Comment: @n_palum oops, thanks. And its a fork in time

Comment: +1 for thinking of an answer I clearly never considered. I've added two more images that may help improve the question / narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: @EngineerToast yeah re those, can you maybe tell us what they are? Doesn't have to be the specific word, just what it is in general. Its hard to tell

Comment: I have added descriptions as the image descriptions you see when editing. I tried to not be too specific because some of them are literally just the word.

Answer (score 4):

Wild guess, is it:

> King

Because

> King-sized Mattress/bed

and

> Orange, colour of the royal family/king of The Netherlands

-

> Landfill/hill, referring to the children's game King of the Castle

-

> Hand of the King, GoT reference

-

> Fork, a move in chess, the game of kings

-

> Stop, what peasants do when approaching a king, not something a king does

-

> 7 wonders, fit for kings

-

> 8 moons of Neptune, god/king of the sea

Apologies for the bad formatting, the spoiler thingies were being weird

Answer (score 3):

> Red

Title:

> Like a red pickup truck?

Body:

> [Red bed, a type of rock](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_beds)
>  Red Fire
>  'red trash' is a term for a redhead, according to the [Urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=red%20trash) **warning: NSFW!**
>  Red-handed
>  [Red fork is a town in Oklahoma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Fork,_Oklahoma)
>  Red sign
>  [Red Pyramid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Pyramid)
>  The Moon turns red during an eclipse.

Comment: That's not mars

Comment: Right, it looked like a planet, so the *red planet*. Is that the only thing wrong?

Comment: I don't think red pickup truck is very convincing.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil - no, but I was stumped :/

Comment: +1 for thinking of an answer I clearly never considered. I've added two more images that may help improve the question / narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: They're real things and those are real pictures (not an artist's rendering) but they're not planets.

Comment: Yes, I see now that they're moons, @Engineer.

Answer (score 3):

Since the OP has already commented on which is the right answer, I just thought I'd throw my two cents in for the last two images:

> The seven wonders of the world will leave you [awesTruck](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjwrsCiwaLTAhWHr1QKHdfvB2EQFgg3MAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.merriam-webster.com%2Fdictionary%2Fawestruck&usg=AFQjCNEC4NCE6re0XRniWvRBGo7W47YB_A&sig2=5RkkvKr6sI9MMwhwozkCOw&bvm=bv.152479541,d.cGw)
>  Some puzzlers seem [moonsTruck](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiUmcPcwKLTAhXlw1QKHUJdCG4QFggxMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.merriam-webster.com%2Fdictionary%2Fmoonstruck&usg=AFQjCNFZ_zGn4DJ5_Uip-97rKTZirIAV4Q&sig2=3N7ELFz8pfi430DcKAfQLA&bvm=bv.152479541,d.cGw) for these types of puzzles.

Answer (score 2):

is it:

> a lift?

because:

> - for title picking up > lifting
>  - bed lift? > like adjustable beds
>  - fire lift > like the elevators firemen use
>  - trash/garbage truck lift > are they the things on the sides of the trash  trucks that picks up the bins and dumps them in instead of people?
>  - hand lift > the things people use in like um warehouses, like fork lifts
>  - fork lift
>  - stoplift is like a shoplifting prevention program
>  - idk what that thing is but it looks like its a spring or air pressured device that could life things up?
>  - truck lift > like the beds of a truck that dump stuff out
>  - random pyramids thing may be the fact that they needed lifts to build them? or some type of pulley system
>  - moon lift is like the whole idea that there should be an elevator you can take to the moon or something like that

idk if this is right but some of them fit?

Answer (score 1):

Mom, get the camera.

Isn't it

> global warming?

Hardly a word if you ask me.
Skip over the rest of this if you don't want to know my answer. I have no idea why ">!" didn't make it a spoiler.

> The bed is warm the fire is warm
> the hand is the hand humans have in global warming
> the other stuff is all something that contributes greatly to global warming.
> The fork for example is our food
> the landfill is pollution
> the other two are industry - I don't know what those are.
> The bonus images are civilization and other celestial bodies.
> The bodies are vulnerable to warming.
> Civilization is the cause of global warming.

Am I right?